# Run a Spring boot application in the background jenkins slave --windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins

I have a spring boot application with embedded tomcat in it. I need to run this application in Jenkins the problem is that the build goes into an infinite loop.

`javaw -jar myjar.jar`

does the same thing as mentioned above. It was mentioned somewhere in SO that if we append start with the above mentioned code it will work.

`start javaw -jar myjar.jar`

the issue with this is that Jenkins build are completed now, but the application doesnt run.

Is there any way i can solve this issue ?

Note:
Jenkins and salve is running on windows.

Comment: Can you please share the error logs you are facing?

Comment: @GajananKulkarni there aren't any  because the application works fine when using javaw, but  appending the start in front of javaw doesnt work, im guessing the application isnt getting started

Comment: Okay. But do you have any server level logs? means as soon as you hit  start javaw -jar myjar.jar, you should be capturing logs in either in Jenkins logs or may be in your system? Something should be appearing once you do any transaction over your application.

Comment: Yes I know, the log file is created but nothing gets logged. The Pid file which gets generated when the application is up also doesnt get created.